# Potential performance issues with .NET MVC using NEWID() as UserId in SQL Server in a busy site?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Let's assume that we are building a high traffic site that will be used by millions of people, and we have used the default Membership Provider that comes with MVC's default project with all of the membership infrastructure in place, with roles and everything which is nice.

But by default the primary id of the user created in the database is NEWID(), and it's being used everywhere in the project.

Assuming we are talking about very busy site, are there any performance issues i am looking down the road with using NEWID() as my primary key? Is it even worth my time to convert everything into INT?

Just so you know, the clustered index on the [aspnet_Users] table is created on the unique username and not on the userid (NEWID).

Thanks!

Comment: I would only worry about the performance of NEWID() in a Users table if you expect to be creating hundreds of new users per second...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using GUIDs fore your clustered index, consider using NEWSEQUENTIALID() instead of NEWID().  Using the latter will lead to fragmentation in the clustered index because it generates GUIDs in an essentially random order.

Comment: NewSequentialID is the much better way to create GUIDs if you aren't using them for security (IE go to link X to reset your password) http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=25862&seqNum=7

Comment: You speak the truth re: security.

Comment: One potential limitation of NEWSEQUENTIALID() is that it has to be run on the server, not in the web app.

Comment: While I agree that you can create GUIDs outside of the database, you still have to store it, thus incurring transit to the db.

Answer (score 1):

The NEWID() is used only when you create a new row and insert a new line and a new ID. After that the indexing have the responsibly for the speed of your site, and this is not affected.

Comment: thanks @aristos, so you are saying that storing a guid from newid() as opposed to int in tables with millions of rows and placing index on them will make no difference performance wise?

Comment: @android-developer Yes, because the performance is when you search the guid, not if you lose some small time to create a new one with newid(). The search of the guid is base on index, and the index speed is not affected. Now I hope that you are not confuze with the newid() on the database table that is a parameter of a new id when new row inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research on this subject, and offer the following article:
http://goo.gl/expzC

Answer (score 0):

There are three potential sources of performance issues when it comes to using GUIDs as user IDs:

1. If you use them as either a clustered or nonclustered key, they will cause fragmentation of your user table and/or indexes. This increases the time required for `INSERT`s as well as `SELECT`s.
2. Creating a GUID can take more CPU cycles than finding the next int or bigint.
3. GUIDs are 128 bits (16 bytes) in size, which increases row width (and therefore the time to execute certain queries), and takes more time to retrieve and compare than ints or bigints.

The advantages of using GUIDs are:

1. You can create them on the web tier without requiring a DB round-trip first.
2. They are hard to guess, which can be helpful from a security perspective.

I've written a custom high-performance Membership provider, and I still use GUIDs, for those reasons.